# How to use a flat icon as link to change a route with react router

Tags: react-router, react-redux, material-ui

I'm using redux, react-router and Material-ui to make my App. I have a problem to show the details of an order. When the user click on a flat button, I want this button sends the user to a new url. I try to do this but it doesn't work.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';


const myButton = (props)=(
    <FlatButton label="See details" onClick={()=>(browserHistory.push('/order/1'))}/>
)
export default myButton;
```

Comment: Can you expand on "it doesn't work"? If you check the console, are you receiving any errors?

Comment: @PaulS I mean it doesn't go to the route I want to. It does nothing and the console doesn't show anything but a message that I put there to confirm the props

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wrapping your `<FlatButton/>` component inside `<Link to="/order/1">...</Link` tags.

Note: You will have to `import {Link} from 'react-router'`

Comment: It's not the  most elegant solution but it works and thats the important thing

Comment: You can add style={{textDecoration: 'none'}} to Link

Comment: Golinmarq, what would be a "more elegant solution"?